# Procedure in proving inequalities (or bounds) involving minus sign

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality

Usually when we want to bound an expression involving sums, it is easy to proceed by bounding each term separately since we "do not lose" too much using the triangle inequality $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$ where $x$ and $y$ denote expressions.

My question is: having something like $|x-y|$ and knowing that $|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$ is too rough but having the feeling that $|x-y|$ is still finite. What is the alternative procedure to follow?

For instance, in an integral expression:
$$A:=\left| \int_0^1 (f(x)-g(x)) dx \right|<\infty$$
without using
$$A \leq \int_0^1 |f(x)-g(x)|dx \leq \int_0^1 (|f(x)|+|g(x)|)dx.$$

Actually, concretising more: I know what $|\int_0^1 f(x)dx|\leq C_1$ and $|\int_0^1 g(x)dx|\leq C_2$ and $C_1-C_2<\infty$ but it turns out that $C_1+C_2 = \infty$. So if only I could preserve the minus sign...

Is there a standard way? Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much for any hint you may have!

Comment: As far I know, there is no general technique. Normally estimating the absolute value of difference is done using other results (e.g. monotone/dominated convergence, Fatou's lemma, etc.). Triangular inequality is often too rough in these cases.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, in the special case g(x) = -f(x), then |f(x)-g(x)| <= |f(x)|+|g(x)| is a tight inequality, and you can't do better. Hence, there's no general way to do better.

Comment: Also note that when you have $C_1-C_2<+\infty$ but $C_1+C_2=+\infty$ you have $C_1$, $C_2$ are both infinity. So the bound $|\int f(x)dx|\leq C_1$ (and for $g$) does not give too much information... These cases are really dependent on the explicit form of $f,g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtaining a sharper bound than the trivial one $|a-b|\le |a|+|b|$ is usually referred to as *exploiting cancellation*. There is no standard way to do that.

Comment: Yes, exactly, here it seems one should exploit the cancellations that might occur.. I see, what a pity :(

Comment: Is there somethng like $|a-b|\leq |a| - |b| + C$ where $C$ is a suitable extra factor?

Comment: @Martingalo: Not in general. The point is that $b$ could be close to $-a$, in which case the only possible bound is the trivial one. You need to use some specific property of your problem to exploit cancellation.